# I am getting a "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." in my ASP.Net Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, razor-pages

I am really struggling with getting my ConnectionString from the appsettings.json file. I have looked through a lot of samples but most are using Entity Framework and or are using the older StartUp.cs example. My application is not using either one of those two options. Currently my Void Main looks like this.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);

    var app = builder.Build();

    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
          
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.Run();
}
```

And the is my DataAccess file where I am trying to read the connection string.

```
public class DataAccess
{
    private static string connectionstring;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DataAccess(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        connectionstring = _configuration.GetConnectionString("P51InvConnection");
    }

    public static async Task<DataTable> ExecuteDataTableAsync(
        string storedProcedureName)
    {
        return await ExecuteDataTableAsync(storedProcedureName, null!);
    }

    public static async Task<DataTable> ExecuteDataTableAsync(
        string storedProcedure, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        DataTable dt = default;

        Console.WriteLine(connectionstring);

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                using SqlConnection conn = new(connectionstring);
                conn.Open();
                using SqlCommand cmd = new(storedProcedure, conn);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 3;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                    }
                }

                using SqlDataAdapter da = new(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return dt; //?? throw new Exception("DataTable empty or null");
    }

    public static SqlParameter Parameter(
        string parameterName, object parameterValue)
    {
        SqlParameter param = new()
        {
            ParameterName = parameterName,
            Value = parameterValue
        };

        return param;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

in the `ExecuteDataTableAsync` method. Also, I have verified that my connection string is named `P51InvConnection` is the `appsettings.json`.

Edited to include the contents of the appsettings.json file.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "P51InvConnection": "Data Source=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;"
  }
}
```

One more edit. This is the first call to the database using the DataAccess class but I don't think the issue is here because this does work if I copy and paste the connection string from the appsettings into the SqlConnection initialization.

```
public static async Task<List<Entry>> EntryList()
{
    List<Entry> entryList = new();

    DataTable dt = await DataAccess.ExecuteDataTableAsync("[dbo].[OpenTransfer_Select]");

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Entry entry = new()
        {
            Id = Convert.IsDBNull(row[IdColumn])
            ? 0
            : Convert.ToInt32(row[IdColumn]),
            UserId = Convert.IsDBNull(row[UserIdColumn])
            ? string.Empty
            : Convert.ToString(row[UserIdColumn]),
            ItemNumber = Convert.IsDBNull(row[ItemNumberColumn])
            ? string.Empty
            : Convert.ToString(row[ItemNumberColumn]),
            EntryDate = Convert.IsDBNull(row[TransferDateColumn])
            ? Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1900")
            : Convert.ToDateTime(row[TransferDateColumn])
        };

        entryList.Add(entry);
    }

    return entryList;
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(connectionstring)` prints what?

Comment: Please let us see your appsettings file, at least the relevant part.

Comment: The error message pretty much says it all. Your connection string in `SqlConnection` class. Toyr connection string is read from the `P51InvConnection` property in your settings file. So there is no `P51InvConnection` in your `appsettings.json`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Console.WriteLine(connectionstring) is null.

Comment: @AFract I edited the post to show the contents of the appsettings.json file.

Comment: @Slepoyi prior to posting the question I verified it was there but I must have made a mistake with the syntax because the application is not finding it. I did modify my post to include it now.

Comment: @BuckHicks As far as I can see, settings file is fine. Are you sure it's available at runtime ? It must have in VS properties Action="Content" and "Copy if newer" (or always) to be sure. You can also mark it as mandatory while loading it when you initialize configuration system.

Comment: @AFract I just checked those settings and they are as you stated. And I can read the contents from the string from the Console.Writeline in the program.cs. I just can't read it from the DataAccess class.

Comment: Could you post the .cshtml.cs where you use the DataAccess class. Not all action, the controller with 1 action which use this class is enough.

Comment: @QiangFu I added it to the original post but I don't think the problem is there because the application will work when I copy and paste the connection string from the appsettings into the SqlConnection.

Comment: It appears that my constructor in DataAccess is never being hit, which is why the configuration is null. I moved the configuration to the IndexModel and it worked as expected. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is static method cannot visit configuration by injection. But if you try make a new configuraion builder it will work.

```
        public static async Task<DataTable> ExecuteDataTableAsync(
        string storedProcedure, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            var connectionstring = configuration.GetConnectionString("P51InvConnection");
            Console.WriteLine(connectionstring);
        }
```

---

A better solution
create a static `ConfigurationHelper.cs`

```
    public static class ConfigurationHelper
    {
        public static IConfiguration config;
        public static void Initialize(IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            config = Configuration;
        }
    }
```

In program.cs add

```
ConfigurationHelper.Initialize(builder.Configuration);
```

Then you could get any configuration value in the static method.

```
        public static async Task<DataTable> ExecuteDataTableAsync(
    string storedProcedure, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            var connectionstring = ConfigurationHelper.config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("P51InvConnection").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(connectionstring);
        }
```